# Linked Data Source problems

Tags: workflow, document-library, data-view-web-part, tasks

I have some few questions regarding how to make Linked Data Sources work.

- Is there a way to have the column headers be able to sort by
  ascending or descending (this is not too important but is welcome) ..
  when I create a ListView it automatically does that but for
  DataFormWebPart it does not.
- Is there a way to make it so I can have a checkbox and approve? What 
  I am actually joining in the linked data source is a Workflow Task
  List and a Document Library.
- Lastly, is there a way I can link to the Workflow Task item? So far, 
  I can only display text but when I just reference the Workflow Task
  List as data source, I have a column with Title (links to document
  with edit menu). I want to also have a link to the Workflow Task item
  through the Linked Data Source.

Hope you can help! Thank you!

For more information here is what I have:

Document Library which uses Form Template as its content type. This mainly contains the details regarding the item.

Workflow Task list which contains the workflow tasks which gets added whenever an item in Document Library is added. This list only contains task columns such as task comments, task name, etc.

When I create a Data / ListView for the Workflow Task list, I get options whether I can approve / reject as well as link to the Workflow Task item [Title (linked to document with edit menu)] to access the form I need to complete the workflow task.

What I want is to display more item details which SHOULD come from the Document Library. But since they are different, I can't. This is why I set-up a Linked Data Source.
What I am having problem now is specifically implementing the feature of "Approve/Reject" and "Link to workflow task item [Title (linked to document with edit menu)]" for the DataView of Linked Data Source.

Hope I have explained it better. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to sort and filter data view webpart using this link http://zioed.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/filter-on-headers-in-data-form-webpart-with-linked-data-source-sp2010/

Comment: Please add to your answer a summary of the steps outlined in the link you provided. If the link in your answer breaks in the future, your answer will no longer be helpful.